# An access token is required to request this resource FQL issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql, access-token, facebook-insights

I have a command line application which executes a query.  Here is the code.

Problem is that it receives an access token of the form "abc...|xyz...".  There is 
no session portion. But the token returned is useless for executing my query to 
select insights for a page of mine.  Help !!

```
       const string permissions  = "manage_pages,read_insights,offline_access";

        dynamic oauthClient = new FacebookOAuthClient() ;
        oauthClient.AppId = username ;
        oauthClient.AppSecret = password ;

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject() ;
        parameters.scope = permissions ;
        parameters.response_type = "token" ;
        // parameters.grant_type = "client_credentials" ;

        dynamic result = oauthClient.GetApplicationAccessToken(parameters);
        string token =  result.access_token ;  
       // token comes back as "abc...|xyz..." 

        var fb = new FacebookClient(token); 
        string query = " select metric, value  " + 
                       " from insights  " + 
                       " where object_id = MY_PAGE and " + 
                       "       metric in ( 'page_impressions' , 'page_stories') and " + 
                       "       end_time >= end_time_date('2012-02-21') and " + 
                       "       end_time <= end_time_date('2012-02-11') and " + 
                       "       period = period('day') " ; 

        dynamic result2 = fb.Query(query) ;  // Exception generated on this line.

        return result2 ;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: BTW - the end time stuff is a cut & paste error.  Should be end-time between 2012-02-11 and 2012-02-21. The token issue is my issue right now.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is from Facebook and it is simply saying you don't have a valid token to make the request. You must request a user access token using OAuth. After you have a valid access token you can make your request with the following code:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("valid_user_access_token"); 
string query = "YOUR FQL QUERY HERE";
dynamic result = fb.Query(query);
```

To learn how to get a valid access token read the Facebook documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Two questions: So would it be a user access token or page access token? Also this is supposed to be a batch application which pulls metrics on a regular basis, hence we want to eliminate all user logins entirely.  Is there any way to have a FacebookOAuthClient().GetUserAccessToken(parameters) method or a FacebookOAuthClient().GetPageAccessToken(parameters) method in the API?

Comment: (It pulls page metrics on a regular basis).  Hence it appears the App auth token is insufficient.